# cannot deploy a contract with web3j

Tags: web3j

I am able to generate the contract just fine, and able to create a wallet, but when I try to deploy the contract on testrpc, I always get an exception saying I dont have enough funds. How can you initialize a wallet using web3j that has initial funds in it?

I create the wallet using WalletUtils, and then use the following code to initialize that account I created with ether while launching testrpc

```
byte[] keys = Keys.serialize(wallet.getCredentials().getEcKeyPair());
String result = new String(Hex.encodeHex(keys));
String privateKey = result.substring(33, 65);
```

Then I try to deploy a contract using that wallet I created.

Sorry, edit to the original question, I cannot launch testrpc because I getting 'private key length is invalid'

My real question should be, how do I create a wallet using web3j, get the private key from it, and use that to initialize testrpc with that private key having funds?

Comment: `ganache-cli` (formerly `testrpc`) by default gives each test account 100 ether to start with. So I don't know why you wouldn't have enough funds. Perhaps you can share the code you're running to deploy the contract and tell us more about the account you're using to do it.

Comment: So there is something I dont understand

here is my process:
1. Create a wallet using WalletUtils.generateFullNewWalletFile(PASSWORD,new File(keyStorePath));
2. Launch testrpc from java
3. deploy the contract

Comment: You'll need to use one of the accounts `testrpc` creates for you. Those have ether preloaded in them. Don't create your own account.

Comment: I see. But how can I get them out from testrpc and then have them accessible through web3j?

Comment: `testrpc` has an option `--account=<private key>,<amount of wei>`. I don't know how you're launching it, but perhaps you can pass that option.

Comment: You can either specify what accounts you want, or the default accounts `testrpc` makes are the same every time. (They're displayed when you launch `testrpc`.)

Comment: I stand corrected... current `ganache-cli` versions seem to use a different set of accounts each time. But I believe back when it was `testrpc` (perhaps the version you're using), the accounts were hardcoded.

Comment: I think you are right about testrpc. I  know how to use the --account flag, and did it in my testing using truffle. I guess the root question now is, given the private key used in the --account flag, how can I get wallet credentials that work with that private key in web3j? I looked through WalletUtils and the Wallet files and they dont seem to have methods to take this as a parameter.

Comment: i've never used Web3j before and am not set up to test it, but from skimming the code, I think [`Credentials.create("<private key here>");`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/6910ec514c465d273a3878a090287faa72a0e12f/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/Credentials.java#L35) should give you what you need.